# Java Web Application open excel document in linux server

Tags: linux, web-applications

I have a web application written in java 8 that is deployed on a Debian GNU linux server without desktop.
On this linux server, libreoffice is installed in order to open the excel file.
The part of reports that this development in java with POI libraries and I want that at the end of the excel document, it can be opened from linux and displayed to the user.
I have read about two options:

This option our linux does not support:

`Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("path/to/your/file.xls"));`

The following commands do not throw errors nor do they show the document.

`Runtime.getRuntime ().exec("xdg-open" + file);`

`Runtime.getRuntime ().exec("--calc" + file);`

Comment: Please do not say "thank you" or similar. See : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Please use backticks around code. So that code becomes readable like so: `code`

Comment: If I understand your question you are trying to open an excel document in a web application. Could you clarify if you are trying to open the document on the users computer(aka the computer visiting your web app), or on the server.

Comment: Hi, the application is deployed on the linux server and is run from said server

Comment: Try something like: `final Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xdg-open", new String[]{"/path/to/exec/file/test.xls"});
        exec.waitFor();
        System.out.println(new DataInputStream(exec.getErrorStream()).readUTF());` The `println` is there so that you see if any errors occur

Comment: Also make sure that you are able to open excel files with `xdg-open` on the command line

Comment: And lastly how are you running/deploying your web app? If its within a docker container or similar it won't be able to open excel outside of the docker container

Comment: I do not manage the server.
The person who manages it says that the server recognizes the xdg-open command.
When deploying .war on the server, console output println is also not feasible.
We do not use docker container.
From my PC, the excel document is opened without errors with the Runtime and Desktop classes.The desktop class is normal to run well on a PC that has a desktop installed

Comment: Then get some other way of logging errors? and log any errors written to stderr. I suspect this will be needlessly difficult to implement if you do not have access to the server.

Comment: Project managers access the server from webadmin.
I will rerun the xdg-open and --calc commands if there are any errors.